# define startMonth for jqtimeline plugin in a webmap

Tags: javascript, date, leaflet

I created a webmap with timeline function by using leaflet.js and [jqtimeline](https://github.com/ozeetee/jqtimeline) plugin. Do you know a possibility to not just define the startYear but a startMonth with jqtimeline plugin? The reason is that my datasets start in November and the timeline should begin with Nov and not Jan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really providing an answer here, but it seems to me that jqtimeline is a very simple plugin; if you want to do some tweaks on it, you might as well look at many other timeline plugins. In your case, D3 would do the job really well.

So my (non) answer: I don't think you can set a startMonth in jqtimeline, and I would use another library if you intend to custom greatly the timeline.